# How to use vue-tour?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Im trying to use vue-tour, following the exact steps from the guide i got this error
https://github.com/pulsardev/vue-tour
[image]

**Steps**

1. Adding vue-tour on the main.js
2. Add steps into data
3. Add component and div steps in the template

**NOTE**

I know it say specific call component:{vue-tour} doesnt work, how to call it?

Answer (score 2):

The error was really silly, i though this line of code have not importance to make it work

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueTour from 'vue-tour'
require('vue-tour/dist/vue-tour.css') // I WAS SKIPPING THIS LINE OF CODE, i added and now it works
Vue.use(VueTour)
```